# What are the good iPad VNC clients for controlling a Mac locally?

Tags: macos, mac, vnc, ipad

Not fussed about controlling a Mac over the internet, or controlling a Windows PC. Just controlling a Mac on the same home network as the iPad.

Free is good, but reliability and a less fussy interface are worth money.

Answer (score 1):

Not really much in remote control over just LAN that wouldn't work the same anywhere else, but you can check out [this rundown](http://www.tuaw.com/2010/05/03/hands-on-with-ipad-vnc-clients/).

Answer (score 1):

The only one I have personal experience with is [iTeleport for iPad](http://www.iteleportmobile.com/ipad). It isn't free, but I found it to be super-easy to set up and use.

Answer (score 0):

Mocha VNC Lite, which is free, seems to work alright so far.

To get it to work with Apple’s Screen Sharing feature, you need to set up Screen Sharing in a specific way: see their [Snow Leopard setup guide](http://www.mochasoft.dk/wizard_w2ml.htm).

The interface isn’t as simple as it could be, and the setup guides don’t have the clearest writing (in English anyway), but once I found and followed the instructions everything worked fine.